# Choosing DB for my big table

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a table with something like 60gb in my DB (using ram memory) that I want to get out to other DB... It's only one table with two columns (ID and text). And the only thing that iam doing on this DB is simple write and read request (1 object each time by id). This DB should get a lot of read and write request (web application). Iam wondering should I use mongodb or elastic or maybe there are something better for me?

Comment: I think those who down vote, need to have courtesy to post the reason. It will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a key-value store problem. Though both MongoDB and Elasticsearch should work well for it too. What are you using now — Redis or Memcached maybe?
Do you know the size of the value (text)?

I assume you have (at least) one other datastore for other workloads in your system. Maybe you can use the same for multiple tasks? Reusing operational knowledge is definitely a win.

Other than that there is not enough information to make a hard argument for any system IMO.